# 4 bytes hash algorithm to compare small text (normally less than 2 kb)

Tags: algorithm, text, hash, duplicates, crc

I am developing a piece of software that need to check duplicate small text *(normally less than 2 kb)* using **pre-calculated signature (4bytes)**. Currently , I've implemented CRC32 (4byte) to achieve this purpose but I suspect that CRC32 would generated a lot of duplicate values. I know it is impossible to make it really unique but at least I want to minimize this probability.

**-- UPDATE 1 --**

**NOTE:** I can not increase the size of hash bytes. It costs me a lot of storage. I am talking about entries size more than 1,000,000. for example 1,000,000 * 4 byte = 4,000,000 bytes. I cannot use MD5 because it takes 16 bytes!

**-- UPDATE 2 --**
I did not want to open the whole problem but now I have to do it.

My project is a dictionary engine that can search a lot of independent databases to find the users' asked phrase. All results must be prepared instantly (auto-complete feature). All text data is compressed, so I cannot decompress them to check the duplicated results. I have to store hash values from compressed text in my **index**. So hash bytes increase index size and **disk I/O** to read, decompress and decode index blocks (index blocks is also compressed). The hash values are generally un-compressible. The design of this software forced me to compress everything to meet the user's needs (using in **embedded** systems). Now, I want to remove duplicate text from search result using hash values to avoid (un)compressed text comparison (which is unreasonable in my case because of disk I/O).

It seems that we can design a custom checksum that meets the conditions. For example, I store text length in 2 bytes and generate 2-bytes checksum to check duplicate possibility ?!

I appreciate any suggestion in advance.

**-- UPDATE 3 --**

After a lot of investigations and using the information that are provided by answers, thanks to all of you, I found that **CRC32** is good enough in my case. I ran some statistical benchmarks on my generated CRCs, after checking the duplicate values, the result was satisfying.

thanks to all of you.

I will up-vote all answers.

Comment: Why do you think crc32 will produce more/many duplicates? Compared to what?

Comment: You may combine with other hashes or even use 2 times CRC32 - one for whole text and one for odd/even chars or whole text after XOR 0xFF (or similar).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I cannot use md5 because of its length. check the question update.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just faced with some collisions

Comment: @i486 I am restricted to 4 bytes! please check the question update.

Comment: The entropy in an MD5 hash is well distributed, you can just take the first or last 4 bytes. But the results will be similar to CRC32. You are fighting the [birthday paradox](https://www.google.nl/search?q=birthday+paradox++hashing) here.

Comment: @greybeard 
 
Please check update -2

Comment: `[4ex] text length in 2 bytes [&] 2-bytes checksum to check duplicate possibility` - with `normally less than 2 kB`, you have 5 bits with little information, which _worsens_ your collision rate.

Comment: You can look at [perfect hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) to get ideas - computation of that function (or the parameters, if you go with the approach mentioned there first) is _very_ costly for the amount of data mentioned and probably only feasible for a (semi)static collection of texts, if at all.

Comment: @greybeard why 5 bits ? I have 16bits for checksum and 16 bits for length checking.

Comment: @greybeard 4 bytes is my ideal size but it can be 6  bytes.

Comment: `why 5 bits [redundancy]` 11 bits will do to encode lengths up to 2048 - extending the allocated bits beyond that adds almost no information. Suggestion: just don't fret about the (few) collisions you will get. You will almost never have to do a full compare if there are many more hash values than texts (satisfied with one million texts and 32 bit hash). _Might_ be different with _hard real time_ where late results mean substantial damage, but `auto-complete` reads UI to me. (OTOH, a 6 byte checksum _would_ drive the probability of any collision down to one in _hundreds_ of text collections.)

Comment: Your Update 2 is not intelligible. What are "duplicated results"? "duplicate text"? What does it mean that "I cannot decompress them", but later "to avoid (un)compressed text comparison", which means you can do it? You'll need to explain what it is that you're trying to do. As you noted, a hash match means only that the hashed text might be equal to an entry with the same hash. (Including a length is just another form of hash with lower strength.) A hash mismatch is the useful thing, since it allows you to greatly reduce the possible entries to compare directly. But you must compare to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further knowledge about `small text`, the best you can hope for is each hash value equally probable, and most of 2³² 4-octet-values used. Even then, you are more likely than not to have a collision with just about 77000 texts, let alone a million. With a few exceptions (Adler32 coming to mind),     well-known hash functions differ very little in collision probability. (They differ in difficulty to produce collisions/given values on purpose, and in computation/circuit cost.)
→Chose a compromise between collision probability and storage requirements.
For easily computed checksums, have a look at [Fletcher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum) - Adler32 is very similar, but has a an increased collision probability with short inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you get into hash collision you have to check if text is equal. The best way would be to count how many time it happens to have collision make some statistics and if it looks bad optimizing it. I got this idea that you could build 2 different hash values crc32 and md5 (or Luhn or whatever you like) and check for equality only if both hashes have same values.

Comment: I cannot use md5 or anything more than 4 bytes. check the question update.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar in one of my projects. In my project i used something called a **BLOOM FILTER** , [watch](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC-I7J6YTPAhUEqo8KHdM4DHkQtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DbEmBh1HtYrw&usg=AFQjCNHOeJZNP-OXd7mCmo4fX_8Sjo4n8w&bvm=bv.132479545,d.c2I) about the entire thing here and how to implement it , Bloom filter reduces the chances of **HASH COLLITIONS** massively thanks to its use of several hashing algorithms (however its possible to simulate multiple hash functions using just one hashing function but that what we are here for.) .. Try this out !! it worked for me and will work for u as well

[An actual working implementation of a bloom filter](https://github.com/MagnusS/Java-BloomFilter)